# lost in quotation marks

Tags: excel, vba, string, quotes

I did look at other questions on this topic.  I know the issue is escape ".  The problem is I am overwhelmed with them and not sure about why a triple """ is required, "" other places.

The initial problem was brought on by trying to run a shell command and referencing file paths with spaces in them so the path has to be contained in quotes.  My understanding is I need something in the format  of:

```
"Program path" "File path"
```

to show up in CMD

to get there I have been using the following:

```
If PrintHC = vbYes Then
    ProgramString = """C:\Program Files (x86)\PDFtoPrinter\PDFtoPrinter.exe"" "
    ElementString = """ & SubmissionDir & ""\"" & SiteNum & ""\"" Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4) & "".pdf"""
    PhotoString = SubmissionDir & "\" & SiteNum & "\" & Left(Filename, Len(Filename) - 4) & "_Photos.pdf"""
    Shell (ProgramString & ElementString)
    Shell (ProgramString & PhotoString)
End If
```

I am pretty damned sure its just a matter of the right number of quotes in the right places, but I am lost in my iterations of of various """ and "" and " attempts.

Comment: I always like `Debug.Print`ing the attempts to see what the string actually is in the Immediate Window, a side note.

Comment: I added it to the watch and looked at the combined value of ProgramString & Element String

Comment: ^ That works too.

Comment: I can't get quotes where I think I need them.  I either get an error on the line when entering them or I get the wrong thing showing up

Comment: If the parh of the file has spaces in then it needs to be in double quotes too `"file name with spaces"` so `"""c:\program files\"" ""C:\document files\file""`  You have the string `"`s round it too don't forget :)

Comment: I noticed that when doing a """  I actually wind up with "" at the start of the path.  When I try to do "" then everthy blows up on me and goes out the window.

Comment: Create your string using single quotes to represent the embedded quotes, then `Replace(yourString, "'", """")` before passing to Shell

Comment: Thank you all for the multiple approaches on how to deal with it.  I am attempting the approaches as we speak.

Comment: I found putting the """" at start and end really simplified things.  Basically @TimWilliams approach is what I wound up doing in the end.  Though I did it manually as apposed to a function.  It worked in the end.